# Register a C++ method to C calllback by using std::function.target

Tags: c++

I'm planing to use a C lib which have a function requires to register a callback function:

```
int add_listen(void (*listener)(const char* param));//C code
```

But I met a "invalid use of const_cast" error when I'm trying to do this:

```
class A_Interface{
public:
A_Interface():listenerCB{[this](const char* param) {
      this->onReceived(std::string(param));
  }} {
add_listen(listenerCB.target<void(const char*)>());
};
//will be overrided by sub class
virtual void onReceived(const std::string param) = 0;
private:
std::function<void(const char*)> listenerCB;
}
```

Is there any other way to pass this **onReceived** to **add_listen**?

Comment: I don't think `target` does what you think it does.

Comment: Unfortunately, no there isn't. You'll be surprised to learn that `onReceived` is not a function. It is a class method. There is a fundamental difference. You can't just call a class method out of thin air. You need class instance to make that happen. You could play games with `std::bind` and `std::function`, but the end result will not be a plain, garden-variety pointer that C code will understand. Unfortunately, this C library's design is not C++-compatible. The library must provide a `void *` opaque pointer that can be passed through, and synthesized into `this`, or an equivalent.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  Thanks to point it out, seems only static function can be passed to here, this C lib maybe is designed only for C.

Comment: @immibis Yes I think I have some misunderstanding on std::function.target, Thanks.

Comment: If you play around with static variables, probably templated ones, you can create the appropriate pointer that a static method will use internally to *then* call into your class, you can get it to work. It just doesn't look particularly pretty.

Comment: Since `add_listen()` doesn't appear to pass a user-defined value to the callback, you could play around with [creating a thunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641489/what-is-a-thunk), which would provide the callable function pointer that `add_listen()` needs, and still be able to carry an `A_Interface*` pointer internally on which to call `onReceive()` with.  This would avoid the need to use any statics at all.  `std::function` doesn't provide thunking that is compatible with C, you would have to create it manually, or find a 3rd party thunking library.

Comment: @AndyG Thanks for your advice .At the very beginning I don't want to have a static function here so I tired to use std::function to do some tricks(but it's useless). Right now I'm looking for another lib which can provide a interface with a void * to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the native CB mechanism in a Meyer singleton:

```
typedef void(cb_t)(char const*);

template<
    int(*reg)(cb_t*),
    int(*ureg)(cb_t*)=nullptr
>
class wrapped_cb{
public:
    ~wrapped_cb(){
        if (!ureg)
            return;
        (*ureg)(&call_servant);
    };
    static auto signal(){ 
       static wrapped_cb cb_list;
       return cb_list.signal_prv;
    };
private:
    wrapped_cb(wrapped_cb const&)=delete;
    auto& operator=(wrapped_cb const&)=delete;

    wrapped_cb(){
       (*reg)(&call_servant);
    };

    static void call_servant(char const* s){
        signal()(s);
    };

    boost::signal2
       <decltype((call_servant))>
          signal_prv;
};

//...

wrapped_cb<&add_listen>::signal()
.connect([](char const* s){
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
};

wrapped_cb<&add_listen>::signal()
.connect([](char const* s){
    std::cout<<s<<" v2"<<std::endl;
};
```

Comment: @Alex.Don.Scofield you're welcome. As the description was short, I actally expected somebody complains. Have fun & let me know whenever any defect you detect in that design.

Answer (score 0):

As @SamVarshavchik said:

> The library must provide a void * opaque pointer that can be passed through, and synthesized into this, or an equivalent

So seems there is no "pretty" way to pass this **onReceived** to **add_listen**, or create a thunk as @Remy Lebeau mentioned.